# store UIColor in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, uicolor

I'm trying to store a UIColor value in an array but it keeps returning null

```
NSMutableArray *mijnArray_kleur = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int count = 0; count <= 100; count++) {    
       UIColor *st = [UIColor blackColor];
       [mijnArray_kleur insertObject:st atIndex:count];
       NSLog(@"%@", [mijnArray_kleur objectAtIndex:count]);
    }
```

this logs: (null)

any ideas how I can store a UIColor or CGColor in an arary (nested arrays gives me similar results)

thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED:

```
NSMutableArray *mijnArray_kleur = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int count = 0; count <= 100; count++)
{    
   UIColor *st = [UIColor blackColor];
   [mijnArray_kleur addObject: st];
   NSLog(@"%@", [mijnArray_kleur objectAtIndex:count]);
}
```

Changes: array outside loop, using addObject.

Comment: edited my example, the whole snippet is inside a for loop, so count is count++ and "addobject" returns same results

Comment: yeah I had my NSMutableArray also outside of my for loop in my original code, copy pasted it wrong here at stackoverflow, sorry :) unfortunately the "addObject" does the same thing as insertObject, so same result: (null)

Comment: There was a conflict on another level in my code, everything works liek a charm now